# XPages How to use an action in an Action Group to stop form submission

Tags: xpages

I have a button built on an Action Group.  I would like to have an action to stop processing the button -- stop the next actions from firing.

I tried a Confirm Action, but the user can click OK and it will continue.  I tried an Execute Script that returns false, but that did not do anything.

I have been reading about event handlers, but not sure how to incorporate this in the button's code itself.

Here is the current code behind the button:

```
<xp:button id="button1" value="Create Account">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
        refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler1">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:modifyField
                    name="ac_Key" value="#{javascript:@Unique()}"
                    var="document1">
                </xp:modifyField>
                <xp:saveDocument></xp:saveDocument>
                <xp:openPage
                    name="/successAccount.xsp">
                </xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This simple example uses the confirm action to only continue if the user selects OK. If the user clicks cancel, nothing further happens. If the user clicks OK, the browser opens the index.xsp page.

```
<xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
    <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true" refreshMode="complete">
        <xp:this.action>
            <xp:actionGroup>
                <xp:confirm message="Sure?"></xp:confirm>
                <xp:openPage name="/index.xsp"></xp:openPage>
            </xp:actionGroup>
        </xp:this.action>
    </xp:eventHandler>
</xp:button>
```

**Update:** This example uses a condition on the actionGroup that can prevent the actionGroup from executing if the condition is false:

```
<xp:actionGroup condition="#{javascript:validateSomething()}">
    <xp:save name="/opskrifter.xsp"></xp:save>
</xp:actionGroup>
```

Comment: I tried the Confirm action, but the OK will let the user "sneak" by and continue.  I am trying to have some sort of action/script that if a certain flag/field is set to a certain value, it will stop the action group from continuing.  Hopefully that makes sense.  I appreciate the response.

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example of using a condition on an actionGroup